# Why ListView doesn't animate the right item?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with **android:animateLayoutChanges="true"**  attribute.

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

And I have an adapter to add and remove items to the list,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrrayListOfStrings);
```

If I add a String at the end, it animates the new item which is last item on the list,

```
arrrayListOfStrings.add("Last item in the list");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But If I add the new item at the top of the list, it adds a new item at the top but animates the last list item.

```
arrrayListOfStrings.add(0,"First item in the list");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Is it a bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Animating changes with a `ListView` is a bit trickier than just setting the layout changes flag because of the view recycling that goes on with the Adapter.  There is a series of DevBytes articles that Chet Haase has done explaining the issues and how to do this type of thing correctly here.  Here is, I think, probably the most relevant one to your predicament.

[DevBytes: ListView Animations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs)

**EDIT**

I added a second video in that series that may be more helpful, the focus is on delete but the concept is still the same.  The key to the trick is adding a `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener` as soon as you add/remove an element in the adapter and trigger `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  The listener will trigger after the adapter has updated the list (so if you've added an element that will be on-screen, it will now have a view with a position), but before drawing begins so you can start the animation in that listener.  Look around 9:00 for the relevant example.

[DevBytes: Animating ListView Deletion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCHNAi9kJI4)

Comment: I checked that link already. He shows an example to remove it, which is easy because we get a reference to the view we are going to remove. But when we add it, we don't get a reference to the view that will hold the item we just added.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Android "L", there is a new class called "[**RecyclerView**](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html)", which is supposed to replace the ListView (and GridView), and provide you with a much better way to animate items as they are inserted/removed.

Here's a link about it:
http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/